# Redux-thunk: `dispatch is not a function`

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk, apollo

So, I'm having an issue with an action returning the above mentioned error (See attached image), instead of updating redux state as expected. What am I overlooking here?

**actionCreators.js**

```
export function userToken(token) {
  console.log('userToken has been fired');
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'Graphcool_Token',
      payload: token
    });
  } 
}
```

**App.js**

```
....
// Root Query
const allPostsCommentsQuery = graphql(All_Posts_Comments_Query, {
  options: {
    cachePolicy: 'offline-critical', 
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
  },
});

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
}

export default compose(
  allPostsCommentsQuery,
  connect(mapDispatchToProps)
)(Main);
```

**Reducer**

```
var tokenDetails = function(state, action) {

  if (state === undefined) {
    state = [];
  }

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Graphcool_Token':
      const newState = [action.payload];
      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default tokenDetails;
```

**LoginUser.js**

```
  signinUser: function(emailID, passwordID) {

    const email = emailID;
    const password = passwordID;

    this.props.client.mutate({
      mutation: signinUser_Mutation,
      variables: {
        email,
        password,
      },
      options: {
        cachePolicy: 'offline-critical', 
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
      },
    })
    .then(this.updateStateLoginDetails)
    .catch(this.handleSubmitError);
  },

  updateStateLoginDetails: function({data}) {
    this.props.userToken(data.signinUser.token);
  },
```

store.js

```html
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate} from 'redux-persist';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';
import client from './apolloClient';
import localForage from 'localforage';

const middlewares = [thunk, client.middleware()];

const enhancers = compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
    (typeof window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ !== 'undefined' || process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : (f) => f,
    autoRehydrate(),
);

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  {}, // initial state
  enhancers
);

// begin periodically persisting the store
persistStore(store, {storage: localForage});

export const history = syncHistoryWithStore(
  browserHistory, 
  store
);

if(module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./reducers/', () => {
    const nextRootReducer = require('./reducers/index').default;
    store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
  });
}

export default store;
```

[image]

Comment: can you show how you are creating/configuring store

Comment: Are you importing your actions and bindActionCreators? ie. `import{ bindActionCreators } from 'redux';`
`import { actionCreators } from '../actions/actionCreators';`

Comment: `connect(mapDispatchToProps)`: isn't `mapDispatchToProps` the second parameter to `connect`?

Comment: @PriyeshKumarI have updated my question to show my store.

Comment: @DavinTryon Correct. The only light difference being I'm doing, ```import * as actionCreators from '../actions/actionCreators';```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first argument you should pass to `connect` is `mapStateToProps`, which is a function that receives the `state` and component `props`.. You should add `null` there if you don't need it:

`connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Main)`

BTW, generally speaking, you don't need `bindActionCreators`.. usually returning an object is enough, like:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  someActionName,
  someOtherAction,
}
```

Comment: Your information resolved the issue for me. Many thanks.

Comment: @enapupe THANK YOU!